# Cordova Phonegap Local vs. Hosted Cloud App

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mobile, cordova

I'm wondering what are the pros and cons of having the raw phonegap html files sit on the actual device vs only having a "jumper" page that'll redirect to an app hosted remotely on the cloud.

These are the things that i could think of:

1. offline access - is much simpler when the html files sit on the actual device, otherwise you'll have to use HTML5 offline API. **+1 Local**
2. View Helpers & Embedded Code - Whether building with Rails or Express i'll gain access to view helpers and embedding if i go with a hosted solution, just like when building a "normal" website. **+1 Hosted**
3. Rest API - If i keep the files locally i'm forced to create a completely separate API to handle to handle all server communications (unless going with something like StackMob). While this might be useful later on if decide to multiple clients it's probably overkill ATM. A hosted solution would handle server calls the same way "normal" websites would do.
   **+1 Hosted for simple apps**

Any other Pro's and Con's i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would locate the static files on the device itself. Otherwise, you always have to request the files via GET (bad for traffic and performance especially on mobile devices).

When you want to put your app to the Apple AppStore, you have to care about redirecting to an online WebApp only I think you will get trouble with Apple.